# Different actions with dragging and clicking points in same graphic

Tags: eventhandler, locator

On a graphic (in this example a simple plot), I need two points to move when I drag with the mouse, and these points must move to location {1,1} when I click on them.

This is how I got it to work, but I don't think it's a good way.

```
 DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}},
  EventHandler[  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Plot[t, {t, -3, 3}], 
  Appearance -> Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 10]], 
 "MouseClicked" :> (pt = 
 ReplacePart[pt, 
  First@Flatten@
     Sort[MapIndexed[{#2, Norm[MousePosition["Graphics"] - #]} &, 
       pt], #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &] -> {-1, -1}]), 
 "MouseDragged" :> (pt = 
 ReplacePart[pt, 
  First@Flatten@
     Sort[MapIndexed[{#2, Norm[MousePosition["Graphics"] - #]} &, 
       pt], #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &] -> MousePosition["Graphics"]])]]
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: your code is fine. Perhaps, you could replace the second argument of `ReplacePart` by somewhat shorter `Nearest[pt -> {1, 2}, MousePosition["Graphics"], 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Each of the following codes is different that yours in this thing that it is not sorting/managing points. Events are restricted to the objects, not the `Graphics`. So this sould be better for overall performance.

#### 1 quick approach

If you don't need `LocatorPane` ability to create new `Locators`, and you don't, this code will do the same but shorter way.

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {1, 2}, pt2 = {2, 3}, eh},
 Dynamic[
  Graphics[{eh@pt1, eh@pt2}, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True]
  , None] ,
 Initialization :> (
   SetAttributes[eh, HoldAll];
   eh[val_] := EventHandler[{Disk[Dynamic@val, .2]},
     {"MouseClicked" :> (val = {1, 1}),
      "MouseDragged" :> (val = MousePosition["Graphics"])
      }]; ) ]
```

Notice `Dynamic[... , None]` around the body, it's purpose is to force definitions from `Initialization` to be read. `None` is to do not repeat this.

### 2 working with LocatorAutoCreate

This code will allow you to make whatever you want:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{.5, .5}, {1, 1}}, eh, val},
 Dynamic[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic@pts,
              Graphics[{eh@pts}, Axes -> True], 
              LocatorAutoCreate -> True, Appearance -> None]
  , None]     
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   SetAttributes[eh, HoldAll];
   eh[list_] := MapIndexed[
      With[{i = #2[[1]]}, EventHandler[Dynamic@Disk[list[[i]], .1],
                          {"MouseClicked" :> (list[[i]] = {1, 1}),
                           "MouseDragged" :> (list[[i]] = MousePosition["Graphics"])}]
        ] &, list];
   )]
```

Comment: It's not efficient, I have to improve it one day. But since thare are no other answers let it stay.